# the same code working another computer but not on my computer

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, watchos

On my apple watch app I am trying User Notifications. On simulator, this code is working on another computer but it isn't working on my computer. I restarted my computer, updated my xcode(other computer's xcode is last version too), I tried different user account on my computer. What can I do? Can it be os x version? What must I check?

For example codes.

InterfaceController.m

```
- (IBAction)btnNotifiy {
    UNMutableNotificationContent* content = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
    content.title = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"Wake up16!" arguments:nil];
    content.body = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"Rise and shine! It's morning time!"
                                                         arguments:nil];
    content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];



    // Configure the trigger for a 7am wakeup.
    NSDateComponents* date = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    date.hour = 13;
    date.minute = 31;
    UNCalendarNotificationTrigger* trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger
                                              triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:date repeats:NO];

    // Create the request object.
    UNNotificationRequest* request = [UNNotificationRequest
                                      requestWithIdentifier:@"MorningAlarmTest41" content:content trigger:trigger];

    UNUserNotificationCenter* center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate = self;

    [center getPendingNotificationRequestsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<UNNotificationRequest *> * _Nonnull requests) {
        NSLog(@"");
    }];

    [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
        NSLog(@"geldi");

    }];
    [center getDeliveredNotificationsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<UNNotification *> * _Nonnull notifications) {
        NSLog(@"");
    }];
}

-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {

    completionHandler();
}

-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {
    NSLog(@"PUsh geldi");
}
```

ExtensionDelegate.m

```
- (void)handleBackgroundTasks:(NSSet<WKRefreshBackgroundTask *> *)backgroundTasks {
    // Sent when the system needs to launch the application in the background to process tasks. Tasks arrive in a set, so loop through and process each one.
    for (WKRefreshBackgroundTask * task in backgroundTasks) {
        // Check the Class of each task to decide how to process it
        if ([task isKindOfClass:[WKApplicationRefreshBackgroundTask class]]) {
            // Be sure to complete the background task once you’re done.
            WKApplicationRefreshBackgroundTask *backgroundTask = (WKApplicationRefreshBackgroundTask*)task;
            [backgroundTask setTaskCompleted];
        } else if ([task isKindOfClass:[WKSnapshotRefreshBackgroundTask class]]) {
            // Snapshot tasks have a unique completion call, make sure to set your expiration date
            WKSnapshotRefreshBackgroundTask *snapshotTask = (WKSnapshotRefreshBackgroundTask*)task;
            [snapshotTask setTaskCompletedWithDefaultStateRestored:YES estimatedSnapshotExpiration:[NSDate distantFuture] userInfo:nil];
        } else if ([task isKindOfClass:[WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask class]]) {
            // Be sure to complete the background task once you’re done.
            WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask *backgroundTask = (WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask*)task;
            [backgroundTask setTaskCompleted];
        } else if ([task isKindOfClass:[WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask class]]) {
            // Be sure to complete the background task once you’re done.
            WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask *backgroundTask = (WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask*)task;
            [backgroundTask setTaskCompleted];
        } else {
            // make sure to complete unhandled task types
            [task setTaskCompleted];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't double post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41425347/the-same-code-working-another-computer - try to improve the original question by e.g. including code, adding more detail, etc.

Comment: i deleted other one my mistake. Next time i'll consider it.

Comment: @eren : Can you tell me what error you are getting exactly while running the project in your computer?

Comment: actually i don't have any error. I am create UNMutableNotificationContent and i give it to UNUserNotificationCenter. When time is come nothing happen on my screen. I added codes too. But with same codes on other computer's simulator brings notification screen.

Comment: Just use the other computer then. That way your code will work. Simples

Comment: I can't take my co-worker's computer every time. And i can't check every time another computer when any code doesn't work on mine. I need to fix it